# R Create a LookBack operation in a DataTable

Tags: r, data.table

I want to do a lookback operation on a datatable. I'd prefer to do it with a single datatable but haven't been able to figure out how to alias things properly. I think I need a way to clearly alias the Date column in each side of the 'join'.

Instead, I've copied the datatable and changed the key column's name in one of the datatables to allow the lookback.

Here's what I've got

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(
  Date = as.Date(c("2013-5-4", "2013-5-9", "2013-5-16", "2013-5-19","2013-5-23", "2013-5-26", "2013-5-29", "2013-6-2","2013-6-10")),
  V1 = c(1,1,1,3,4,9, 2, 3, 1)
)
```

Here's the code that copies the datatable, changes one key column name and does the lookback calc

```
DT2<-data.table(DT) # copy the whole table
setnames(DT2,c("DDate",unlist(names(DT2)[2:length(names(DT2))]))) # changes the column name for date
# add a column in DT by looking up values in DT2
DT[, lookbackmean:=mean(DT2[DT2$DDate < .SD[,Date],V1]),by=Date][, lookback:= paste0(DT2[DT2$DDate < .SD[,Date], V1],collapse=","),by=Date]
```

Here's the output. NOTE: I created a column called lookback that shows the values being considered for the mean for each date .

```
         Date V1 lookbackmean        lookback
1: 2013-05-04  1          NaN                
2: 2013-05-09  1     1.000000               1
3: 2013-05-16  1     1.000000             1,1
4: 2013-05-19  3     1.000000           1,1,1
5: 2013-05-23  4     1.500000         1,1,1,3
6: 2013-05-26  9     2.000000       1,1,1,3,4
7: 2013-05-29  2     3.166667     1,1,1,3,4,9
8: 2013-06-02  3     3.000000   1,1,1,3,4,9,2
9: 2013-06-10  1     3.000000 1,1,1,3,4,9,2,3
```

The problem that I experience WITHOUT creating a copy of the datatable follows

Join the datatable back to itself but doesn't calculate the value. I believe the problem is it can't distinguish the Data columns in the join.

```
DT[, lookbackmean:=mean(DT[DT$DDate < .SD[,Date],V1]),by=Date]
    [, lookback:= paste0(DT[DT$DDate < .SD[,Date], V1],collapse=","),by=Date]

         Date V1 lookbackmean lookback
1: 2013-05-04  1          NaN         
2: 2013-05-09  1          NaN         
3: 2013-05-16  1          NaN         
4: 2013-05-19  3          NaN         
5: 2013-05-23  4          NaN         
6: 2013-05-26  9          NaN         
7: 2013-05-29  2          NaN         
8: 2013-06-02  3          NaN         
9: 2013-06-10  1          NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess I now question you desired result:

```
> DT[, lookbackmean:=  head(c(NA,cumsum(V1)/(1:.N)),-1) ]
> DT
         Date V1 lookbackmean 
1: 2013-05-04  1           NA 
2: 2013-05-09  1     1.000000 
3: 2013-05-16  1     1.000000 
4: 2013-05-19  3     1.000000 
5: 2013-05-23  4     1.500000 
6: 2013-05-26  9     2.000000 
7: 2013-05-29  2     3.166667 
8: 2013-06-02  3     3.000000 
9: 2013-06-10  1     3.000000
```

I suppose you might not really want teh cumulative mean, in which case you should look at the many SO questions that ask for data.table examples using indexing:

Comment: Your math is not equivalent. Not sure how 1.66667 is identified for 2013-05-19. the only thing that makes sense is its using rows 2:4/count(3) = 5/3. That's not how it needs to work. The lookback values above show that for that day should be (1+1+1)/3 (all of the values before that date). i.e. `DT2[DT2$DDate < .SD[,Date],V1]`

Comment: can you direct me to one of the indexing examples? What I've seen is indexing columns within the current row/group.

Comment: This is a slight edit that gives the desired result: `DT[,bah:=head(c(NA,cumsum(V1)/(1:.N)),-1)]`

Comment: Thanks, Frank, ... will incorporate.